# como tomar el valor de un radio button marcado para hacer un condicional?

Tags: javascript, html

Hola que tal? Estoy intentando hacer que según el valor de los siguientes radio buttons me tire distinto resultado, pero no logro hacerlo, mi código hasta ahora:

```
 <div class="contenedorOpciones">

    <form action="">

        <div id="climaPreferido" style="display: block;">
            <p>Clima preferido?</p>
            <input onclick="cambio()" class="inputsRadio climaRadio" value="frio" type="radio" name="clima" id="fresco"><span class="opcion">Frio </span> 
            <input onclick="cambio()" class="inputsRadio climaRadio" value="calor" type="radio" name="clima" id="caluroso"><span class="opcion">Calor </span> 
        </div>
      
        <div style="display: none;" id="zonaGeografica">
            <p>Preferencia:</p>
            <input class="inputsRadio geografiaRadio" type="radio" name="geografica1" required id=""><span class="opcion">Montaña </span> 
            <input class="inputsRadio geografiaRadio" type="radio" name="geografica2" id=""><span class="opcion">Mar </span> 
            <input class="inputsRadio geografiaRadio" type="radio" name="geografica3" id=""><span class="opcion">Rio </span> 
        </div>


        <input id="botonAceptar" type="submit" onclick="aceptar()">
    </form>

</div>
```

Cual seria el metodo correcto para llamar al checked de estos input?
Desde ya muchas gracias. Estoy usando esta funcion pero solo me tira un resultado:

```
function aceptar(){

switch (clima.value) {


    case calor:
      alert("resultado A")
    break;
    case frio:
     alert("resultado B")
     break;

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que buscas es esto:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('climaRadio');

for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++){
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
      var valor = this.value;
      console.log(valor);
    });
}
```

```html
<p>Clima preferido?</p>
<input class="inputsRadio climaRadio" value="frio" type="radio" name="clima" id="fresco"><span class="opcion">Frio </span> 
<input class="inputsRadio climaRadio" value="calor" type="radio" name="clima" id="caluroso"><span class="opcion">Calor </span>
```

Comment: Corregí mi pregunta siendo mas especifico, gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Creo que solo debes capturar tus ids con javascript, jquery o lo que necesites.

```js
const data = document.getElementById('radios');

data.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let form = new FormData(data);
  
  if(form.getAll('clima')[0] === 'frio'){
   alert('escogiste frio');
  }
  if(form.getAll('clima')[0] === 'calor'){
    alert('escogiste calor');
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="radios">
  <label>Frio</label>
  <input type="radio" id="frio" name="clima" value="frio">
  <label>Calor</label>
  <input type="radio" id="calor" name="clima" value="calor">
</form>
```

Comment: Corregí mi pregunta siendo mas especifico, gracias por tu respuesta –

Comment: También edité mi respuesta para que veas cómo podría funcionar usando un form de ese tipo que tienes